# Powershell script to Move files from one folder to other in same document library

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, document

I have a document library "Documents1" which has multiple folders. Trying to write a powershell script to move files placed in multiple sub folders(has to read from .xlsx) to another folder called "redundant" under the same doc lib.
Pretty new to powershell just tried out something below but doesn't help

```
$Web = Get-SPWeb "test.com"
$DocLib = $Web.Lists["Documents1"]           
$filenames  = Get-Content 'F:\sample\test4.xlsx' | Select-Object -Unique

$result = foreach($name in $filenames) {
    $move = foreach ($ListItem in ($DocLib.Items | Where-Object { $_["Name"] -like "*$name*" })) {
        $File = $DocLib.Files.Add($ListItem.Name, $ListItem, $true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Need more information. Sounds like you are trying to move files from multiple sub-folders under the Documents1 folder to "redundant" folder. Is this correct? If so, I do not see "redundant" referred to in your code, What information is present in the xlsx file? Is it the selected file names? And what is the error/result you are receiving when running the above?

Comment: Yes trying to move files from multiple sub folders to Redundant folder. And the XLSX file contains the pdf filenames( example adbc.pdf) which needs to be searched from multiple sub folders to be moved into Redundant. And when I try to run above my powershell window is just getting closed.

Comment: Is reading from the xlsx a hard requirement? To read from an excel you will need to use PSExcel module. If you place the names of the files in a txt file it will be easier.

Comment: no..i initially tried with txt file...no such hard rule of xlsx. Anyway I try just closes my powershell window.And where exactly should I mention the files to move to redundant folder?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't mind having your list of files in a txt file. You can use the below.

```
$SOURCEDIR="C:\Users\YOUR SOURCE DIR\TEST1"
$TARGETDIR="C:\Users\YOUR TARGET DIR\TEST2"
$FILELIST="C:\Users\LOCATION OF FILE LIST\filelist.txt" 

$filenames  = Get-Content $FILELIST
foreach ($file in $filenames)
{
Get-ChildItem -Path $SOURCEDIR -Recurse | Where-Object -FilterScript {($_.name -match $file)}  | Move-Item -Destination $TARGETDIR
Write-Output "File moved " $file
}
```

Comment: I tried the below way but not sure how I can refer the target library to a subfolder in Sharepoint 
document library under the "Documents1"

$Web = Get-SPWeb "test.com"
$SOURCEDIR = $Web.Lists["Documents1"]   
$TARGETDIR=$Web.Lists["Redundant"]   
$FILELIST="F:\users\filelist.txt" 

$filenames  = Get-Content $FILELIST
foreach ($file in $filenames)
{
Get-ChildItem -Path $SOURCEDIR -Recurse | Where-Object -FilterScript {($_.name -match $file)}  | Move-Item -Destination $TARGETDIR
Write-Output "File moved " $file
}

Comment: Tried $TARGETDIR=$SOURCEDIR.RootFolder.Folders["Redundant"]   but get error saying cannot index into null array

Comment: below another way I tried. but doesn't seem to help                                                                               

$Web = Get-SPWeb "test.com"
$SOURCEDIR ="Documents1"   
$TARGETDIR = "Documents1/Quarantine" 
$FILELIST="F:\users\filelist.txt" 

$filenames  = Get-Content $FILELIST
foreach ($file in $filenames)
{
Get-ChildItem -Path $SOURCEDIR -Recurse | Where-Object -FilterScript {($_.name -match $file)}  | Move-Item -Destination $TARGETDIR
Write-Output "File moved " $file
}

Answer (score 0):

This a demo on move files between folders in the same Document library,you could add your judgment conditions,

```
$web=Get-SPWeb "http://sp"
    
    $listName="lib"

$list = $web.Lists[$listName]

$TargetFolder = $Web.Url + "/" + $list.RootFolder.Url + "/"+ "bb"

$sourcefolder=$list.rootfolder.SubFolders["folder"]

$files = $sourcefolder.Files

foreach ($item in $files) {

     $File=$Web.GetFile($Item.URL);

     $TargetPath=$TargetFolder+"/"+$file.name;

     $File.MoveTo($TargetPath);

     Write-Host "Moved Item:"$item.Name;

}
```

Comment: $web=Get-SPWeb "test.com"    
$listName="Documents1"
$list = $web.Lists[$listName]
$filenames  = Get-Content 'F:\users\filelist.txt'
$TargetFolder = $Web.Url + "/" + $list.RootFolder.Url + "/"+ "Redundant"
$sourcefolder=$list.rootfolder.SubFolders["Documents1"]

foreach ($name in $filenames){
foreach ($ListItem in ($DocLib.Items | Where-Object { $_["Name"] -like "*$name*" })) {
 $File=$Web.GetFile($Item.URL);
 $TargetPath=$TargetFolder+"/"+$file.name;
 $File.MoveTo($TargetPath);
 Write-Host "Moved Item:"$item.Name;
}
}

Comment: Tried the above way, but get an error saying cannot index into null array

Comment: Get-Content may not be suitable for reading excel files.

Comment: another method i tried which shows no results


$WebURL="https://test.com/"
$SourceLibrary ="/Documents1"
$TargetLibrary = "/Documents1/Redundant"
$filenames  = Get-Content 'F:\users\filelist.txt'
 
#Get Objects
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
$SourceFile = $Web.GetFile($SourceLibrary)
$Targetfile = $Web.GetFolder($TargetLibrary)
 
foreach ($file in $filenames)
{
Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFile  -Recurse | Where-Object -FilterScript {($_.name -match $file)}  | Move-Item -Destination $Targetfile
Write-Output "File moved " $file
}

Comment: $file_list = Get-Content 'F:\users\filelist.txt' 
$web=Get-SPWeb "https://test.com"
$listName="Documents1"
$list = $web.Lists[$listName]
$search_folder = "Documents1"
$destination_folder = $Web.Url + "/" + $list.RootFolder.Url + "/"+ "Redundant"

foreach ($file in $file_list) {
   
    $file_to_move = Get-ChildItem -Path $search_folder -Recurse | Where-Object -FilterScript {($_.name -match $file)}
    if ($file_to_move) {
        Move-Item $file_to_move $destination_folder
    }
}